# Switch Flex start condition immediately on startup

Tags: flex-lexer

With Flex, is it possible to start parsing in a different start condition than `INITIAL`? I would like to start in an exclusive start condition (`%x something`). I am dealing with a file format that has special rules at the beginning.

Comment: So use INITIAL for that and then switch into another state.

Comment: INITIAL is not exclusive.